# external js file not updating in vs 2013

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, external-js

I created a external js file and use bundle for my asp.net mvc5 project , it works fine and then I added new functions in my external js. I save the latest file but when I run the project and view source, the external js file is not updated, it is the original/previous file and not the one saved in my visual studio. Does anyone encountered this before? thanks for answers!

Comment: Have you refreshed the browser?

Comment: hi , try to bulid your project once and see .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is caused by browser cache. You can press Ctrl+F5 to refresh browser.
Or disable cache in F12 developer tools

[image]

Comment: thanks, for the answer I haven't tried it , what I did is restart the visual studio. but will vote up for your answer. seems right. thanks bro.